# reporting validation error in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a date input on LWC component, which when left empty should give a validation error. I am able to achieve that but the issue that I am facing is after the input gives error and i fill the date value, the error is not rendered empty.Let me show by screenshot
[image: Expected if value is left empty]

[image: when value is entered,the error still persists]

Code:

```
validateFields(){
        let dateCmp = this.template.querySelector(".dateCmp");
        let dtValue =  dateCmp.value;

        if(!dtValue){
            dateCmp.setCustomValidity("Date value is required");
            dateCmp.reportValidity();
            return false;
        }else {
            dateCmp.setCustomValidity("");
            dateCmp.reportValidity();
            return true;
        }

    }
handleSend() {
        if (!this.validateFields()) return;
.............
```

Please let me know how can I achieve this? Any immediate help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a onchange handler in input field will fix the issue for you. This means you validate the value once more on change.

```
<lightning-input class="dateCmp" onchange={validateFields} type="datetime" label="enter a date"></lightning-input>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sanket Kumar ...What if i already have an onchange handler on the input cmp. onchange i am doing this : this.scheduleTime = event.detail.value; and then sending the updated value of scheduleTime..

Comment: Just add the validation piece of code their or call the validateFields method inside that